# Grails GSP suppress output

Tags: grails, gsp

When using functions in a GSP - like add to a list - how can one suppress the output from the return value. Again, "Add" returns true, when added so:

```
${myList.add(myObject)}
```

will output "true" to the screen. Can this be suppressed? Preferably not in a "hacked" manner (using hidden fields etc.).

Answer (score 2):

Why you add an object in the `GSP`? The presentation should be used only to display data, so this code should be in a controller or service.

**EDIT**

I think that you can use the JSP tags to do that: `<% myList.add(myObject) %>`

Comment: Does it matter? It is _the_ only solution the problem, which is far to complex to explain here.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Sergio here, operations like that should be placed in other places.

for the purpose of your problem you can trick it like this

```
${Math.round(10)?"":""}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Well, sadly I have no option to do it in the controller code - broken by design. I've already done similar to your suggested approach, however, I hoped there would be a prettier solution. Thanks Anyway!